# don't know if there's a missing code to show up my text in the center

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is my first time trying something by myself (beginner) , i have wrote these codes and my problem is there's a specific text that wrote , doesn't show up in the application when i run it even tho i get no errors or dead codes and this is what i wrote

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var materialApp = MaterialApp(
      title: 'Unknown driver',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Unkown driver'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return materialApp;
  }}
Widget mylayouWidget() {
  return const Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0,0),
  child: Text(
      "Unknown but available for u!",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
  )
  );
}
```

this is what i got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WSlU.png)

why didn't these show up?

```
Widget mylayouWidget() {
  return const Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0,0),
  child: Text(
      "Unknown but available for u!",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
  )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't call the `mylayouWidget()`. You need to use it on body.

```dart
home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Unkown driver'),
        ),
        body: mylayouWidget()
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling your myLayouWidget. Fixed and made your code easier to read

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  Widget mylayouWidget() {
    return Center(
        child: Text(
            "Unknown but available for u!",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
        ),
    ),
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Unknown driver',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Unkown driver'),
        ),
        body: mylayouWidget()
      ),
    );
  }  
}
```